# Is Keyboard Viewer supposed to work through VNC?

Tags: macos, keyboard, vnc, hotkeys, on-screen-keyboard

I'm connecting to my Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6) from my Windows XP work computer using both TightVNC and RealVNC, and both of those don't give me access to the Option key. So to work around that, I tried using Keyboard Viewer, but that doesn't respond to clicks through these VNC clients. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Keyboard viewer cannot be used to simulate alt, even without VNC. It shows mapping of local keyboard. Keyboard mapping in VNC protocol is a mess.

- Try using different VNC server (VineVNC instead of built-in sharing or vice-versa).
- Try swapping modifier keys in System Preferences.
- [Try keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).

Differnt VNC *client* won't affect sharing in any way. VNC server might collide with OSX's built-in one, but not necessarily – you can configure 3rd party server to use different port.

Comment: I'm using the RealVNC OS X server and XP client, and was able to get the right ALT key to correspond to Option by assigning LeftOptKey to ExtendedChars in the RealVNC Server's expert settings.